# GLM with unequal sample size

Tags: r, anova, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution

I am trying to figure out how to run a GLM with a poisson distribution in R. The data has 4 treatments: $\text{A}(n=16)$, $\text{B}(n=17)$, $\text{C}(n=16)$, $\text{D}(n=20)$, and 2 time periods.  This data is count/area so there are decimals.  Ultimately, I would like to know if there are differences between the treatments.  What is the appropriate way to format these data so that I can run an ANOVA using GLMs with a poisson distribution in R?

Below is an example of the data:

```
time1_A = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39.33,0,0,0,76.22,0,0,0)
time1_B = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39.82,0,0,0,0)
time1_C = c(0,0,63.22,0,0,0,0,0,39.33,0,0,0,45.22,0,0,0)
time1_D = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,79.83,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
time2_A = c(0,0,39.33,0,0,39.33,0,0,0,0,39.33,39.33,79.62,39.33,0,39.33)
time2_B = c(0,0,0,0,39.33,0,39.33,39.33,0,11.94,0,0,39.33,39.33,79.62,0,15.92)
time2_C = c(39.33,0,39.33,0,199.6,119.4,79.6,0,39.33,318.7,199.6,0,39.33,278.6,278.6,238.5)
time2_D = c(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,39.33,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0)
```

Comment: Just looking at the amount of 0s, there is no way that a Poisson is going to fit well to this data